# php WITH ROLLUP for two tables

Tags: php

For a local non-profit org, I'm attempting to summarize donation totals using two MySQL tables: donations and donors. So far, I have this working correctly:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total, donor_id FROM donations
GROUP BY donor_id WITH ROLLUP
```

What I can't figure out is how to present the donor's name (donors.last_name) in the query.

In other queries, I have used WHERE donations.donor_id = donors.donor_id, but that doesn't seem to work in this case. Also, I'd like the results to show the 'total' column in descending order if possible.

Your suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: We don't know the schema. We also don't know what dbms you are using. We don't have any sample input/output data.

Comment: I'm using php to connect with mysql on localhost. Output looks like this:
Donor ID  Total Donations
8 430.00
14 5,400.00
15 200.00